# yii data retrival query

Tags: yii

I have a table `tablename:user`
column names: `name`, `dept`, `area`, `active`. I have added some sample data into the database
But on the grid view i want to display only the data where column with active =1 
Can anyone help me how to add this condition in the query ,I am using mysql database

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    //'reports_to' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Student', 'id'),
    );
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'user_id' => 'User',
        'user_name' => 'User Name',
        'userpass' => 'Userpass',
        'userdept' => 'Userdept',

    );
}

public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id,true);
    $criteria->compare('user_name',$this->user_name,true);
    $criteria->compare('userpass',$this->userpass,true);
    $criteria->compare('userdept',$this->userdept,true);
    $criteria->compare('reports_to',$this->reports_to,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: pls dont add duplicate question. Edit the previous question to add additional deatils